# List View with toggle button in android

Tags: android, list, listview, togglebutton

in my application i have list view with toggle button and textview.Here i am going to perform two actions on the list.

1)click on the toggle button.
2)clicking on the list view item.
both working nice but when i click on the toggle button i performed action based upon the on ,off conditions .But the conditions not working properly.every time it shows off condition.
the following code is bellow

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = null;
        TextView arryText;

        SharedPreferences sh = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(
                "onOrOff", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        Boolean[] onOff = new Boolean[] { sh.getBoolean("SUNDAY", false),
                sh.getBoolean("MONDAY", false),
                sh.getBoolean("TUESDAY", false),
                sh.getBoolean("WEDNESDAY", true),
                sh.getBoolean("THURSDAY", false),
                sh.getBoolean("FRIDAY", true),
                sh.getBoolean("SATURDAY", false) };

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.inflate, null);

            arryText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.inflateText);
            togg = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

            togg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (togg.isChecked()) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ison",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "isoff",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            arryText.setText(days[position]);

        }

        return v;

    }
```

every time i get "is off " can any one help me

Comment: Please check this link . I think you should find solution here. http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/enabling-multi-selection-mode-in-listview-by-adding-togglebutton-using-custom-layout-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All compund buttons (in particular ToggleButton) has it's listener OnCheckedChangedListener, try to override it with togg.setOnCheckedChangedListener() method

Answer (score 0):

Wrong listener for toggle button. mention like this in xml:

android:textOff="@string/no"
android:textOn="@string/yes"

for toggle button and in java code like this:

toggleButton.getText().toString();

This is working code!!! :)